# function with dynamic parameter length

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval, signalr

i want to call javascript (signalR) functions. They only respones if the parameter length is exactly as long as expected!

Thats my try to solve the problem (the string in eval() is generated out of the array length):

```
var ar = [1,2,3];

function test(a, b, c) {
    console.log("a:" + a);
    console.log("b:" + b);
    console.log("c:" + c);
}
test(eval("ar[0], ar[1], ar[2]"));
```

In this case b and c is always "undefined" ... can anyone give me a hint how to solve such a problem?

I want to give as much parameters to my function as my array is long (ar.length) .

thanks :)

Comment: Bad use of eval..., forget that eval exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
test.apply(window, ar )
```

then inside the function you can use [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) to access all the arguments

```
function test(){
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        console.log(i + ':' + arguments[i])
    }
}
```